# Webserver Resources when using Node Driver

Tags: javascript, html, corda

I am currently building a demo for a simple cordapp, and am trying to implement a simple webpage to show an example of interacting with the node. I am launching my nodes using the node driver, and have created custom API's as well as some custom HTML and JS. I am having issues getting changes made to my JS and HTML files to propagate through to being shown on the webserver - and while I know these files are stored with the node I can figure out the correct method to go about getting the node to update these files.

I have tried removing the build folder, rebuilding the project and then running my node driver script, with no luck. I have also tried simply copying the files into build/resources, but I this also doesnt seem to work and I am not sure if this is where nodes run using the node driver actually pull their web resources from. Is there anything I am missing here? Could anyone potentially point me in the direction of a better process to develop and test this? (rather than having to re run my node driver everytime I make a change to either my HTML or JS files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue had nothing to do with the Corda side of things, but rather developing in chrome. Due to chromes caching for some reason old JS file were being used. Resolved by flushing the cache using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (See [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development))